# rCharts - Adding second y axis to time series

Tags: r, rcharts

Does any of the packaged charting frameworks in rCharts support making a time series plot of two series with different y axis? In the case has anyone an example to share?

I have looked at the documentation there is as well as on the charting frameworks web sites but have not found anything.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done in highcharts and most likely others. I have taken the nice work done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes/). A simplified version of that is:

```
library(rCharts)
h <- Highcharts$new()
h$xAxis(categories = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                       'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'))
h$yAxis(list(list(title = list(text = 'Rainfall'))
             , list(title = list(text = 'Temperature'), opposite = TRUE)
             , list(title = list(text = 'Sea Pressure'), opposite = TRUE))
        )
h$series(name = 'Rainfall', type = 'column', color = '#4572A7',
                data = c(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4))
h$series(name = 'Temperature', type = 'spline', color = '#89A54E',
                data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6),
         yAxis = 1)

h$series(name = 'Sea-Level Pressure', type = 'spline', color = '#AA4643',
         data = c(1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7),
         yAxis = 2)
h
```

Which will hopefully give this chart

[image]

Comment: @Ramnath thank you and thanks for all the work you and Thomas Reinholdsson and others have done.

Comment: Thanks you. Realized that Highcharts is commercial software though and would like to use an open library so I keep looking.

Comment: This code is not working in rCharts as of v0.4.1 anyway.  It results in an empty plot.  I have opened a ticket on github and hope to see a resolution, as this is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Ramnath, can we also do mirrored x-axis with another label on top, similarly?

Comment: you now ned to wrap the call to yAxis as such: `h$yAxis(list(list(title = list(text = 'Rainfall')), list(title = list(text = 'Temperature'), opposite = TRUE), list(title = list(text = 'Sea Pressure'), opposite = TRUE)))`