# How do I get multiple subplot in rcharts?

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I have two lines as code below need layout in two row, how to do it in rcharts?

```
h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1$chart(type = "line")
h1$series(data = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5, NA), dashStyle = "longdash")
h1$series(data = c(NA, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4), dashStyle = "shortdot")
h1$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
h1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWIHn.png)

Comment: What do you mean by a "layout in two row"?

Comment: I have add a image what I want, but I don't know how to make it displayed in the question.

Comment: Looks like rCharts supports multiple yAxis, see related topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535665/rcharts-adding-second-y-axis-to-time-series  / https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/319